# How to handle invalid input for Fibonacci Sequence

Tags: java, exception, while-loop, try-catch

I am trying to create a Fibonacci Sequence generator where all invalid input cases have a response before asking the user to try again.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("The Fibonacci Sequence is the series of whole positive numbers where the next number is found by adding up the two numbers before it. \nGive it a try!");
    double number = 0; //
    boolean error;

    do {

        try {
            error = false;
            System.out.println("Enter a number to use as an upper limit. The Fibonacci Sequence will be generated up to that number.");
            number = in.nextDouble();
            if (number % 1 != 0 || number < 0) {
                System.err.println("The Fibonacci Sequence only works with positive whole numbers, please enter a positive integer.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("The Fibonacci Sequence is: ");
                int i = 0;
                int f0 = 0;
                int f1 = 1;
                int fn;
                double value = 0; // changed this to double which is redundant since value is not used
                do {
                    fn = f0 + f1;
                    System.out.print(f0 + " ");
                    f0 = f1;
                    f1 = fn;
                    value = number - f0;
                    i++;
                } while (f0 <= number);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("The Fibonacci Sequence only works with positive whole numbers, please enter a positive integer.");
            error = true;
        }
    } while (number < 0 || number % 1 != 0 || error) ;
}
```

However, when I use try/catch with my do-while loop, I get an infinite loop of the message within catch and the input prompt.

The Fibonacci Sequence only works with positive whole numbers, please enter a positive integer.
Enter a number to use as an upper limit. The Fibonacci Sequence will be generated up to that number........

I am not super advanced in Java yet, so for now I'd like to find a solution using this logic, just find a way to fix my code. Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to program to exit if the input is invalid?

Comment: Don't you want the user to try again in case of error as it happens @RileyGT?

Answer (score 0):

It works for anything except when you enter a non number. It loops because you still have a value in the input buffer so the error keeps repeating.  So you need to remove that input in the catch block as follows:

```
catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("The Fibonacci Sequence only works with positive whole numbers, please enter a positive integer.");
                    error = true;
                    in.nextLine();  // <-- Remove problem input
                }
```

BTW, since you only want positive `ints` why are you prompting for doubles?  You may want to do:

```
int number;
// then later

number = in.nextInt();
```

Here is a slight modification of what I think you may want.  I also included a friendly way to exit the program.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println(
        "The Fibonacci Sequence is the series of whole positive numbers where the next number is found by adding up the two numbers before it. \nGive it a try!");
int number = 0; //
boolean error;

for (;;) { // loop forever (or until user enters 'quit`)
    System.out.println(
            "Enter a number to use as an upper limit. The Fibonacci Sequence will be generated up to that number.");
    try {
        number = in.nextInt();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // input problem, see if user wants to quit
        String value = in.next();
        if (value.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")) {
            System.out.println("Bye!");
            return;
        }
        // some other errored input so force error message
        number = -1; 
    }
    if (number < 0) {
        System.err.println(
                "The Fibonacci Sequence only works with positive whole numbers, please enter a positive integer.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("The Fibonacci Sequence is: ");
        int i = 0;
        int f0 = 0;
        int f1 = 1;
        int fn;
        double value = 0; // changed this to double which is redundant
                          // since value is not used
        do {
            fn = f0 + f1;
            System.out.print(f0 + " ");
            f0 = f1;
            f1 = fn;
            value = number - f0;
            i++;
        } while (f0 <= number);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, I have a lot to learn, thank you!

Comment: @RilyeGT  So do I.  :)